# How to save information on a variable, i.e. (summary(linearMod)), to a pdf?

Tags: r

I am currently creating a plot-portfolio with all kinds of plots, however, some information, namely the exact statistics on my model stored in summary(my_model_name) does not need further plotting but just printing.

So I want this information

```
> summary(linearMod)
[...]
Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-14.7693  -0.8011  -0.0070   0.8408  11.0514 

Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         0.03640    0.13427   0.271    0.786    
lag(Var1)           0.99888    0.00107 933.358  < 2e-16 ***
US                  0.34386    0.05235   6.569 6.88e-11 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.944 on 1577 degrees of freedom
  (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.9982,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9982 
F-statistic: 4.401e+05 on 2 and 1577 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

to appear in my pdf. 
I am creating pdf's with

```
pdf("portfolio.pdf", width=8.9, height=5)
# the code for the plots
dev.off()
```

Is there a solution to my needs?

Comment: This is probably a good use for using an Rmarkdown which you can render to pdf.  This allows you to interweave code, code results (including graphs/plots), and text.  Check this out: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/

Comment: I use this pattern, `gplots::textplot(capture.output(summary(linearMod)))`

Comment: @Nate, do you mean `pdf("my.pdf"); gplots::textplot(...); dev.off();`? Otherwise, it's just another graphic.

Comment: @r2evans yes I intended that snippet to go into the open PDF device where `# the code for the plots` sits now